# Is it possible to arrange the integers $1, 1, 2, 2,..., 1998, 1998$ such that there are exactly $i − 1$ other numbers between any two $i$'s?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, invariance

> Is it possible to arrange the integers $1, 1, 2, 2,..., 1998, 1998$ such that there are
> exactly $i − 1$ other numbers between any two $i$'s?

This is a problem related to invariants and I'm trying to make sense of it by replacing $n= 1998$ with smaller values of $n$, but I cant't figure out how to define a suitable invariant here.

If we pick $n = 4$ we are looking at the sequence $$1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4$$ and the closest I can get to a working configuration is first fixing the $4$'s and then trying to organize the remaining numbers such that they satisfy the property. What I have is $$4,3,1,2,1,4,2,3$$ which works for all $i$ except $i=3$.

Now there should be something obstructing me from being able to get the desired configuration which would lead me to find the invariant, but I'm not seeing what is my obstacle here. Any hints on what to look for?

Edit: I made a mistake there shouldn't be any number between $1$'s. Actually for $n=4$ the configuration $$1,1,4,2,3,2,4,3$$ works.

Comment: The numbers $i$ occupy slot number $m_{i}$ and $m_{i}+i$. Sum of all number of slots is $\sum_{i=1}^{1998}2m_{i}+i$, which should equal $\sum_{j=1}^{3996}j$. They cannot be equal, but why?

Comment: What is $m_i$? @RezhaAdrianTanuharja

Comment: Arbitrary unique number which is the position of the first $i$

Comment: Why not make it $0,0,1,1,…1997,1997$ and require $n$ elements between each pair of $n$s?

Comment: @MJD Or is it possible to arrange the integers $1,1,2,2,...,1998,1998$ such that any two $i$'s are $i$ positions apart?

Comment: @MJD Or see exercise 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Expanding your attempt

When $n=1$, there is sequence $1,1$.
When $n=2$, it is impossible.
When $n=3$, it is impossible.
When $n=4$, there is $1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4$. Or $1,1,4,2,3,2,4,3$ as you have found.
When $n=5$, there is $1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5$.
When $n=6$, hmm, it looks impossible.
When $n=7$, hmm, it looks impossible.
When $n=8$, there is $1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8$.
When $n=9$, there is $1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 7, 8, 4, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 9$.

It looks when $n=0,1\pmod4$, there is such a sequence. Otherwise, there is no such sequence.

We would guess there is no such sequence when $n=1998=2\pmod4$. A proof is given below.

##### Parity argument

As you might have suspected, the invariant/classification is on parity.

Suppose we have arranged the integers $1,1,2,2,...,1998,1998$ in a row of $1998 * 2= 3996$ slots. Let us color the slots black and white alternatively as black, white, black, white, … Note that there are as many black spots as white spots.

- For each odd integer $i$, the two $i$'s should be arranged in two slots of different colors.
  So all odd integers occupy as many black spots as white spots.
  There are $3996-997*2=1998$ slots not occupied by the odd integers.
  Half of them, $997$ spots are black.
- For each even integer $i$, the two $i$'s should be arranged in $2$ slots of the same color.
  Since $997$ is not a multiple of $2$, all even integers cannot fill the $997$ black spots left.

##### Exercises:

1. Write another proof as suggested in Rezha Adrian Tanuharja's comment.
2. Prove the there is no such sequence when $n=1999$.
3. Construct such a sequence when $n=2000$.
4. Construct such a sequence when $n=2001$.
5. What happens if we should arrange the integers $1,1,2,2,...,n,n$ such that there are exactly $i$ other numbers between any two $i$'s?

Comment: Just for fun, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxbOL.png) is a nonsensical answer by ChatGPT.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Family restaurants here often provide a free packet of four crayons, and with two packets I have looked at the solutions for the $n≤4$ cases. For many years I'd wondered whether there were solutions for $n≥5$, but I was never given more than four colors of crayons, and I never remembered to think about it after my meal was served.

Comment: @MJD Thanks for sharing your story.